# Не могу запустить бота Discord на Python

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

Как решить проблему?

Код:

```
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from asyncio import sleep

PREFIX = '!'

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX)

@client.command()
async def ehelp(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0xff0000, title='Title')
    embed.add_field(name='name', value='value', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='name', value='value', inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

token = ''
client.run('token')
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 293, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 247, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 18, in <module>
    client.run('token')
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 718, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 697, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 660, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 509, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 297, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
```

Comment: мне кажется, что вместо строки 'token' вы пытались передать переменную. Очевидная же ошибка

Comment: и да, не нужно палить токен от бота здесь. Сделайте пустую строку в блоке кода.

Answer (score 2):

```
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from asyncio import sleep

PREFIX = '!'

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX)

@client.command()
async def ehelp(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0xff0000, title='Title')
    embed.add_field(name='name', value='value', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='name', value='value', inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

token = ''
client.run(token)
```

ты должен передавать переменную, а не строку

Comment: браво, маэстро!

Comment: Опять ошибка... При том всё та же...

Comment: @MixailKazakovIT, а вы случайно ли не скопировали весь код из ответа?)
Значение `token`-то здесь пустое. Свое подставили?

Comment: подставил я токен свой:)

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в токене.

Возможно вы пытаетесь использовать `self-bot`.
Попробуйте

```py
client.run(token, bot=False)
```

Однако это противоречит `TOS Discord`, пробуйте на свой страх и риск